# How can i return a JSON object and a zipped folder simultaneously from on end point in spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

I am trying to Generate a number of CSV reports along with their PDF versions all zipped and sent with a corresponding JSON object containing summaries of the exported files.The summaries is to be viewed by the user before download.

One simple way of doing it would be to return a JSON object from the API then generate the reports from the client which in this case is implemented in react.This solution however is a bit cumbersome as i cannot seem to find a robust file processing library that can offer all the functionalities that i would need; that is generating the CSV files , generating PDF files then ultimately zipping them for download.
If there is such a solution that i am not aware of that then i would take that route.

This brings me to my alternative which i am currently pursuing, which is to generate the zipped folder along with the summaries and return it from the end point to the client.

How can i return a JSON object and zipped folder simultaneously from on end point in spring boot if at all possible and how would i consume such a response in javascript. Note that setting the object as a custom file attribute has size limitations and other file systems do not support such according to the docs  [File attribute docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#user)

Comment: Look at (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73946415/9560693). it's also working with zip file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path I'd suggest would be to base64 string encode the file and set it as a property of the returned object, which then could be serialized to json

Convert a file to a base64 string:

```java
byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(filePath));
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch surely makes things a whole lot simpler and way cleaner

Comment: :) glad to help, have fun !