# How to return both JSON response and Byte Array of file in Springboot RestController Response while downloading a file

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, content-disposition

I am developing a rest controller to download a .docx file into the client system. My code is working fine as the file is getting downloaded. Now I want to enhance the response. My requirement is to also send a JSON payload in the response along with the .docx file content, something like

```
{"message":"Report downloaded Successfully"}
```

incase of successful download or with a different message incase of failure.

Below is my restcontroller code:

```
@RestController
public class DownloadController {
    
    
    @PostMapping(value="/download",
            consumes = {"multipart/form-data"},
            produces = {"application/octet-stream"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> downloadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadFile){
        
        //business logic to create the attachment file
        
        try {
            
            File file = new File("path_to_.DOCX file_I_have_created");
            byte[] contents = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.attachment().filename("survey.docx").build());
            
            return new ResponseEntity<>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

How do I modify my response code to send both the JSON message and the byte[] contents so that the file gets downloaded and I can see the JSON message in the response preview tab in the chrome or response body in postman?

UPDATE: I tried to define a response class like below

```
public class Downloadresponse {

private byte[] content;
private String message;

//getter,setters

}
```

With this change in place, I am getting below exception:

```
Resolved [ HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class ...Downloadresponse] with preset content-type "application/octet-stream”]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. HTTP doesn't allow you to defined multiple content-types on 1 request/response. That being said, you could send the byte array base64 encoded as part of a json response but would need to handle it in the front-end (if you have any) as it would not trigger the file download process of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom class which hold your current content and message . So you can return that class in the response

```
ResponseClass
{
byte[] contents;
String message;
}
```

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work.

Comment: then you can add this message into header like below 
                      String msg="Report downloaded Successfully";
   headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
   headers.put("message", Collections.singletonList(msg));

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, while I try the solution of putting headers.put("message", Collections.singletonList(msg)); could you please see the update to my question about the exception I am getting. Any idea on how to solve that issue?

Comment: Another way todo is you can store the message into file and return that file in the response . So response will have 2 files .

Answer (score 0):

You can send a json object that contain the message and the file as encoded64 string.

And in the client side you decode it and download it.

```
public record MyRecord(String message, String encodedStringBase64, String filename) {}


...

try {
        
        File file = new File("path_to_.DOCX file_I_have_created");
        byte[] contents = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(contents);
     
        MyRecord record = new MyRecord("Report downloaded Successfully", encodedString, file.getName());

        return log.traceExit(ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers)
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/json")).body(record));
} ...
```

Comment: here an example how to download it in JS [Gist Github](https://gist.github.com/yehoudaB/8745e1409c280eaf24962667d1a06e01)